# Key object is modified after insertion in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I read a table from Excel and pass the data into a hasp map. However, it looks like one of the elements used in key is overwritten after the insertion. I am not able to figure out what's wrong. I'd really appreciate, if someone could help me out.

//AssetCity class definition

```
public class AssetCity{
    public int asset;
    private int city; 
//constructors
//setters
// hashCode and Equals methods
```

In the main function, I first read the excel sheet and create my map.

```
XSSFSheet _pi = myWorkbook.getSheet("pi"); //get the sheet              
Map<AssetCity, Integer> pi = new HashMap<AssetCity, Integer>(); //create map            
    for(int i = _pi.getFirstRowNum() + 1 ; i <= _pi.getLastRowNum(); i++){              
        AssetCity pair = new AssetCity();   
        Row ro = _pi.getRow(i); //get each row
    for(int j = ro.getFirstCellNum()+1; j <= ro.getLastCellNum()-1;  j++) {
    Cell ce = ro.getCell(j); //go through each column 
    pair.setAssetCity(i, j); //create the key that will be inserted
        int val = (int) ce.getNumericCellValue(); // get the cell value                      
      // System.out.println(pair.toString()+ " "+ val);
    pi.put(pair, val); // insert into the map
        }                       
}
```

When I use `System.out.println(pair.toString()+ " "+ val);` before the insertion operation, what I get is shown below, which is correct and matches with the values that I have in the Excel.

```
asset_city [asset=1, city=1] 0

asset_city [asset=1, city=2] 0

asset_city [asset=1, city=3] 0

.....

asset_city [asset=5, city=3] 1

asset_city [asset=5, city=4] 0
```

Now, after I am done with the for loop, I iterate all the element in the map.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<AssetCity,Integer>> itr1 = pi.entrySet().iterator();
    while(itr1.hasNext())
        {
          Map.Entry<AssetCity,Integer> entry = itr1.next();                 
                  System.out.println(entry.getKey().toString() + " = " + entry.getValue());
```

Now, as you can see, city values in the key looks all the same.

```
asset_city [asset=2, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=3, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=4, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=5, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=1, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=2, city=4] = 1
asset_city [asset=3, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=4, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=1, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=2, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=3, city=4] = 1

asset_city [asset=1, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=2, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=1, city=4] = 1

asset_city [asset=5, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=4, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=5, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=3, city=4] = 0

asset_city [asset=4, city=4] = 1

asset_city [asset=5, city=4] = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the data in the same `AssetCity` object for every cell in a row.

To fix, declare and initialize your `AssetCity` object inside the inner loop instead of the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

Because the**AssetCity** pair is being created outside of the inner loop, that created pair is being updated each iteration of the 'j' loop.

Perhaps you would like to create the a new instance of the **AssetCity** pair in the inner loop like the following snippet. Which will mean it is a new instance each iteration of the inner 'j' loop.

```
XSSFSheet _pi = myWorkbook.getSheet("pi"); //get the sheet              
Map<AssetCity, Integer> pi = new HashMap<AssetCity, Integer>(); //create map            
for(int i = _pi.getFirstRowNum() + 1 ; i <= _pi.getLastRowNum(); i++){              
    Row ro = _pi.getRow(i); //get each row
    for(int j = ro.getFirstCellNum()+1; j <= ro.getLastCellNum()-1;  j++) {
        Cell ce = ro.getCell(j); //go through each column 
        AssetCity pair = new AssetCity();   
        pair.setAssetCity(i, j); //create the key that will be inserted
        int val = (int) ce.getNumericCellValue(); // get the cell value                      
        // System.out.println(pair.toString()+ " "+ val);
        pi.put(pair, val); // insert into the map
    }                       
}
```